# IOS program crashes when I touch outside of keypad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, first-responder

When I touch on a text field called `tv_Name`, it brings up the keypad but then, when I touch outside the keypad, the program crashes.

In `ViewController.h`, I have declared it thus:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tv_Name;
```

and this is the code for hiding keypad in `ViewController.m`:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.tv_Name resignFirstResponder];
}
```

The code immediately above throws an exception:

> **2013-12-21 13:09:36.027 HerdProfile[818:70b] -[HerdProfileViewController tv_Name:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10901ce90
>   (lldb)**

Comment: Can you paste your code in detail?

Comment: self.tv_Name.delegate = self;

Comment: @nico, i'm new to ios and objective c, where should i put that piece of code?

Comment: you can put it in viewdidload method. so try there.

Comment: Have you clear with your problem if not then i will tell you other process to resolve it.

Comment: @nico, I fixed the problem. It was to do with wiring the .xib label to the .m file, and then I deleted the method in the .m file only without wiping out the reference in the .xib file. This was causing the crash. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work ok for me.

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tvNameTextField;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.tvNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

[image]

Are you sure you have your UITextField hooked up to your controller properly?  There should be a little round dot beside your @property if it is connected properly (see screen grab)